# Best way to implement paging for partial views in mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

What would be the way to implement a paging system (Previous, Next) for partial views? My first thought was to implement separate partial views that would contain the inputs to decide whether the page can go previous, next, or finish. From there the controller would decide where to route what from the input.

What would be the best practice way of implementing such a scenario?

Comment: Are you paging a data grid of some sort, or pages of content (like a blog or similar)? If it's the former, there are NuGet packages you can leverage rather than doing the work yourself.

Comment: @TiesonT. i would be implementing a paging system for creating data. For example the first partial view would contain Customer information (fn, ln, email), the second partial view would contain Payment information. And lastly, the third partial view would contain a Summary

Comment: Ah, so a wizard-style "registration" form. I think I've seen a good example of that. Let me see if I can find it again.

Comment: Here's an interesting implementation of a wizard on MVC: http://afana.me/post/create-wizard-in-aspnet-mvc-3.aspx. It doesn't use separate partials for each "page", but you might still like the implementation.

Comment: @PabloRomeo That's the exact one I was thinking of. It's a good base, if we're understanding the OP's requirements correctly. Thanks for finding that.

Comment: @PabloRomeo In fact, why don't you post that as an answer so that I can upvote it. :)

Comment: @TiesonT. Just did, too bad SO doesn't have some mechanism for shared responses, hehe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an interesting implementation of a wizard on MVC:
http://afana.me/post/create-wizard-in-aspnet-mvc-3.aspx

It doesn't use separate partials for each "page", but you might still like the implementation.